# Let $0≠v∈\mathbb R^2$. Compute the angle between $v$ and $Av$ where $A$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $0≠v∈ \mathbb {R^{2}}$. For $0≤θ ≤π$, let $A= \begin{bmatrix}\sinθ&\cosθ\\-\cosθ&\sinθ\end{bmatrix}$

Then the angle between $v$ and $Av$ is

1. $π-θ$
2. $θ$
3. $(π/2)-θ$
4. $0$

How do I start finding the angle between these 2 unknown vectors? I'm missing out on the other form of the matrix A. Just a little help to get started will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: Yes but what's the significance of the matrix A?

Comment: If $v=(a,b)$, then 
$$Av = \begin{bmatrix}\sin \theta & \cos \theta\\ -\cos \theta&\sin \theta\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\sin \theta  + b\cos \theta \\-a\cos \theta +b\sin \theta \end{bmatrix}$$
Geometrically speaking, you are rotating $v$ by an angle $\theta$

Comment: Okay, thanks! Anti clockwise right?

Comment: That makes option 2. the correct choice then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation matrix $R_{\theta} =\begin{bmatrix}\cosθ &-\sin\theta \\ sinθ&\cosθ\end{bmatrix}$ when applied to a vector $v$ rotates the vector $v$ anticlockwise through $\theta$ angle.

Now for clockwise turining its given by $R_{-\theta} = \begin{bmatrix}\cosθ&\sinθ\\-sinθ&\cosθ\end{bmatrix}$

Now comparing to the given matrix $A$ we see that we just need to apply $\theta \rightarrow(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta)$ so that we get $R_{-(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)} = \begin{bmatrix}\sinθ&\cosθ\\-\cosθ&\sinθ\end{bmatrix}$.

That is $v$ gets rotated clockwise through an angle of $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$ when $A$ is applied on $v$ or the angle between $v$ and $Av$ is $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$!

More you can find at  - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html

Comment: Yes I was missing out on matrix $A$ being the rotation matrix! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of some help, can you please give some reference to the question like from book or from exam?

Comment: http://igmlnet.uohyd.ac.in:8000/entrance%20question%20papers%20-%202014/MSc%20-%20Mathematics%20-%202014.pdf Question no. 1 ! I'm trying to solve this question paper!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference!